# Relation between Hilbert-Schmidt inner product and tensor products

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, tensor-products

Suppose $A$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, then when is it true that

$$\langle Ax, x \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = \langle A, x \otimes x \rangle_{\text{HS}}, \quad \forall \, x \in \mathcal{H}$$

I know from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator#Space_of_Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operators) of Hilbert-Schmidt inner product and the definition of tensor product that

$$
\langle A, x \otimes x \rangle_{\text{HS}} = \sum_{j \in J} \langle A e_j, \langle x, e_j \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} x \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
$$
where $\{e_j\}_{j \in J}$ is an arbitrary ONB of $\mathcal{H}$. However, I am unable to simplify further. Any help would be appreciated.

If the above result is incorrect, in general, I am interested in going from an expression of the form $\langle Ax, x \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ to an expression of the form $\langle A, x \otimes x \rangle_{\text{HS}}$. How could I do that?

Also, I would really appreciate some references where I can look into these kind of results in more detail.

Comment: Shouldn't this follow simply from a resolution of the identity? You have outer products of $e_j$ in there which sum to $I$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to functional analysis. Could you be more detailed about what you mean by the outer product of $e_j$ and how it follows from resolution of the identity? Let me read up on resolution of the identity till you reply.

Comment: @CameronWilliams forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is use an orthonormal basis whose first element is $x/\|x\|$. Then
$$
\langle A,x\otimes x\rangle_{\rm HS}=\operatorname{Tr}(A(x\otimes x))=\langle A(x\otimes x)\tfrac{x}{\|x\|},\tfrac{x}{\|x\|}\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle, 
$$
since $(x\otimes x)x=\|x\|^2\,x$.

Comment: This is brilliant! Just to confirm one thing though: $\langle A , x \otimes x \rangle_{\text{HS}}$ should equal $\text{Tr}(A^* (x \otimes x))$, right? and therefore we have $\langle A , x \otimes x \rangle_{\text{HS}} = \langle A^* x , x \rangle$. Or is it true that $A$ being Hilbert-Schmidt must also be self-adjoint?

Comment: No, $\langle A,x\otimes x\rangle$ is $\operatorname{Tr}((x\otimes x)^*A)$. And $x\otimes x$ is selfadjoint.

Comment: Okay, must be different conventions then? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator#Space_of_Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operators) says $\langle A, B \rangle_{\text{HS}} = \text{Tr}(A^* B)$.

Comment: It's about convention. If you want to use the physicist's convention, then you also need to use it in the definition of the trace.